# How can I prevent Toplevel() from opening two additional windows?

Tags: python, tkinter

I have a program that uses `Tkinter` and I'm trying to assign a command to a button in my `root` window that opens **one** additional window. I'm using `Toplevel()`, but whenever I click the button I've assigned the command to, **two** windows open, one with my `root` window's name and one with the name of the additional window I've assigned.

I've tried using `.withdraw` and `.destroy`, to hide or remove this extra `root` window, but nothing seems to be working.

Here is my code:

```
import Tkinter
from Tkinter import *

root = Tk()
root.wm_title("VACS")

# # Top label # #

SetParameters = Label(text="Set Parameters", width=110, relief=RIDGE)
SetParameters.grid(row=1, column=0, columnspan=7, padx=5, pady=5)

# # Spatial freq settings # #

SpatialFreq = Label(text="Spatial Frequency", width=15, relief=RIDGE)
SpatialFreq.grid(row=3, column=0, padx=5, pady=5)

From1 = Label(text="from")
From1.grid(row=3, column=1, padx=5, pady=5)

Select1 = Spinbox(from_=0, to=10, width=25)
Select1.grid(row=3, column=2, padx=5, pady=5)

To1 = Label(text="to")
To1.grid(row=3, column=3, padx=5, pady=5)

Select2 = Spinbox(from_=0, to=10, width=25)
Select2.grid(row=3, column=4, padx=5, pady=5)

Steps = Label(text="in steps of")
Steps.grid(row=3, column=5, padx=5, pady=5)

Select3 = Spinbox(from_=0, to=10, width=25)
Select3.grid(row=3, column=6, padx=5, pady=5)

# # Contrast settings # #

Contrast = Label(text="Contrast", width=15, relief=RIDGE)
Contrast.grid(row=5, column=0, padx=5, pady=5)

From2 = Label(text="from")
From2.grid(row=5, column=1, padx=5, pady=5)

Select4 = Spinbox(from_=0, to=10, width=25)
Select4.grid(row=5, column=2, padx=5, pady=5)

To2 = Label(text="to")
To2.grid(row=5, column=3, padx=5, pady=5)

Select5 = Spinbox(from_=0, to=10, width=25)
Select5.grid(row=5, column=4, padx=5, pady=5)

Steps2 = Label(text="in steps of")
Steps2.grid(row=5, column=5, padx=5, pady=5)

Select6 = Spinbox(from_=0, to=10, width=25)
Select6.grid(row=5, column=6, padx=5, pady=5)

# # Test button # #

Test = Button(text="Begin Test", width=25, command=Top)
Test.grid(row=6, column=0, columnspan=7, pady=5)

# # Directory input window # #

def Top():
    Toplevel()
    Toplevel().wm_title("Directory")

root.mainloop()
```

If you click "Begin Test" in the `root` window, two extras pop up. I only want the one that says "Directory."

Any ideas?

Comment: Unrelated, but your naming style doesn't match convention. There isn't anything inherently wrong with it, but take a look at [PEP8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) if you care about that kind of thing.

Comment: Thanks, I'll keep that in mind. I'm not a big-kid programmer, so I didn't know about naming conventions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're creating two, since `Toplevel()` is the constructor call:

```
Toplevel()
Toplevel().wm_title("Directory")
```

Instead, create one and save it:

```
top = Toplevel()
top.wm_title("Directory")
```

Comment: When I tried this, I got "AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute 'wm_title.'" Also, the window that pops up has the title "VACS" instead of "Directory"